# .net core handle PostreSQL db exceptions

Tags: postgresql, exception, .net-core

I have a .net core web api. Db is PostreSQL. I have a simple POST request that create an entity with two fields:

```
    public class ClientDto{
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public int ClientId{get;set;}
}
```

ClientId - FK foreign key to table Clients.
Some client (Postman for exapmle) execute request, but in data model send ClientId that not exists in db.

I have global exeption handler and there I handle db exception, but exception object don't include separated information.
I would like to show to user beautiful message something like "Client with id = 1 not exists".
What the best practis to handle db exceptions?

May be before save object in db I need check if client with id = 1 exists in db? But it is an additional query.

Answer (score 0):

> May be before save object in db I need check if client with id = 1 exists in db? But it is an additional query.

I'd do this.

If your client doesn't give you good information in its exception then your probably better to do the additional query. If you're querying on an indexed field (which i'd expect given you are using a foreign key) then it will be a very quick query.

Exception throwing and catching is fairly expensive anyway and i'd probably be happy enough with the extra call.